# Should I include jQuery in my ASP.Net MVC 4 bundle or use the CDN?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cdn

If I'm bundling my js files together should I still get jQuery from a CDN?

Comment: Although @casperOne closed this, I'll answer here. I think you should use the CDN for any JavaScript that is likely to see a performance increase from the CDN, i.e. the core jQuery files (lib and UI). Any specific jQuery plugins that you are using can be bundled.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why it was closed. Seems like a fairly simple, focused question.  Maybe casperOne doesn't believe in using CDNs ;)